# Pass custom header to Kendo Upload Remove url

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-upload

I would like to know, how to i pass custom header to KendoUpload's Remove url?

I see some example for passing header while upload file.
http://www.telerik.com/forums/custom-authorization-header-for-upload

Please help.

Thanks
Sudip

Answer (score 1):

The remove event of KendoUpload misses the needed e.XMLHttpRequest object which is available in the upload event. You can try setting removeUrl: "empty-remove-url" and do your own custom remove ajax call like this :

```
function onRemove(e) {
  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: actual-remove-url,
    data: e.files,
    beforeSend: function(xhr) {
      xhr.setRequestHeader("custom_header", "value");
    }
  });

}
```